# How to check if partition table exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql, I want to check if a partition table exist and return a boolean.

```
EXECUTE('SELECT not EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = ''table_' || replace(cast(loop_table.table_suffix  AS varchar), '-', '_') ||''');') INTO _empty;
```

This seems to return true either way when I run it.

Comment: Hard to answer as long as we don't know what `loop_table.table_suffix` is and what tables there are.

Comment: If you just want to check is a table exist or not and execute something depend on this. just use `If Exist` with  `information_schema.tables`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe table_suffix contains dates so it adds dates to the end of the table such that the table name wouldbe table_2020_08_30 (for example).

Comment: @T.Peter I get a syntax error related to the "if" in a if exists statement

Comment: `if exists (...) Begin ... End` don't just replace exists into `if exists`.

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me a:
select exists (SELECT * from information_schema.tables 
 where table_schema = schema and table_name = table_name);

which would return a boolean

Comment: `select to_regclass(concat('table_', ...)) is not null` might be easier to deal with